# Interprocess communication between multiple nodejs apps

Tags: node.js, ipc

I am working on a project in which I am using nodejs. Project runs multiple nodejs apps(processes) simultaneously. I want share data between these processes and synchronize their execution. 
Does nodejs has something similar to "message queue" and "Semaphores" to
share data and synchronize execution of process.
I know nodejs has asynchronous I/O and I should't be using blocking I/O operations in my app but some file read/write operations in the app needs blocking I/O.

I can use socket.IO for information sharing but synchronization using socket.io gets messy.

In-short, I am looking for a node module which can host a shared message queue for IPC and also act as a scheduler to block and run processes in the app.

Answer (score 1):

Google "nodejs message bus" - there are quite a few alternatives to Socket.io and ZeroMq including  [Simple Bus](https://github.com/ajlopez/SimpleBus) and [Postal.js](https://github.com/postaljs/postal.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can try ZeroMQ, it has bindings for node.js: http://www.zeromq.org/bindings:node-js

Comment: Thank You but data sharing model of ZeroMQ looks more like socket.io.